# Stop traversing when the first required node is reached in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Sorry if the question seemed vague :) The query I'm looking for is a little specific. Consider the following branch in a graph:

( a:Detector {prop_x:False})-->( b:Category {prop_x:False})-->( c:Category {prop_x:True})-->( d:Category {prop_x:True})-->(...) and so on

Now I want get all the parent nodes of `a` till I reach a node where the property `prop_x` of a node is True and then stop. i.e. I want the path:

( a:Detector {prop_x:False})-->( b:Category {prop_x:False})-->( c:Category {prop_x:True})

I tried the following query:

`match path=(child:Detector)-[*]->(parent:Category {prop_x:True}) return path`

but the path I get also includes the node ( d:Category ) as it also has `prop_x` True.

**I want ALL such paths in the graph starting with** `Detector` **nodes till the first "parent"** `Category` **node with** `prop_x` True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression you have there will match all paths that start with a node with the label `Label` and end with a node with the label `Label` and where `prop_x` is `true`.  I assumed that you knew where you were going to start and started with a node with the `name`of `A`.  Then matched all path's from there that end with and `prop_x` of `true`.  This could include paths where it goes `true - false - true` too.  I sorted the resulting paths ascending by path length and kept only the top match.

```
match path=(child:Node {name: 'A'})-[*]->(parent:Node {prop_x:True})
return length(path), nodes(path)
order by length(path)
limit 1
```

**NEW BELOW**

Updates per updated question, "How to find all such paths from all `Detector Nodes`?"

I thought about this for a while and this is what I came up with...

```
// first match all of your detector nodes
match (d:Detector)
with d
// then for each detector node match the paths that end with True
match path=d-[*]->(parent:Category {prop_x:True})
// for each detector collect the length and matching nodes
with d, [ length(path), nodes(path) ] as path_match
// order by the detector name and path length so they are grouped and sorted
order by d.name, length(path)
// then collect all of the length, path collections so there is one
// row per detector
with d, collect(path_match) as path_matches
// then return the first Detector and the first (i.e. shortest) collection in the collection of paths
return d.name, path_matches[0]
```

Comment: thanks, what do I do if I want to get all such paths in graph ? (I am editing the question)

Comment: whew, that worked like a charm! Now I am going try to understand what you did :)

Comment: Excellent - be careful. I think if you have a lot of `Detector` nodes or extra lengthy chains or both this query could churn a bit.